# Rails - How to prevent direct URL access to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller method that redirects to a url.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    return '/appli/key_registrations'
end
```

However, I want that users cannot access this url on their own (for example, if they enter `myapp.com/appli/key_registrations` in the url bar, they are redirected to somewhere else). How can I do that ?

Comment: What is special about that page that you don't want users to access it later?

Comment: When people access to this page, it creates objects in my models. I only want this to happen when the page is called by my redirection method `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)`

Comment: Well then, in that page, check if objects already exist. If they do, redirect. If not, user must have come from that after_sign_up helper.

Comment: Or create a temporary random token (which expires in, say, 1 minute) and append it to that url. In the handler of that page check validity of the token. If token is a) present, b) not expired and c) hasn't been used yet, then the user must have come from after sign up redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to set a cookie in your redirection method and check for/remove that cookie in the registrations page.

Another alternative is to check `request.referer` for the referring URL, but bear in mind that the referrer can be spoofed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the first solution!